# I'm working with template variable on context, but no matter what i do, the context from view function is not displaying, what did i do wrong?

Tags: django-views

def index(request):

```
context = {
    "name": "patrick",
    "age": 23,
    "country": "British",
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

then in html

## hello,{{name}},you are {{age}} years old, and you are {{country}}

Comment: Can you post the whole HTML please. Also can you show/describe what is getting displayed?

Comment: ... and please format your codes with code markups. Also, as a new contributor you might find this information useful: [ask].